# Ext4-FS / "itable block" error on boot

Tags: boot, 16.04, external-hdd, ext4

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 from an external hard drive and have not had any issues up until now.  While attempting to boot, I get...

```
EXT4-FS error (device sdb1): __ext4_get_inode_loc:4077: inode #262150: block 1048608: comm dubs-daemon: unable to read itable block
```

Can someone explain what is going on and help me solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Filesystem error, potentially bad block on hard drive. if issue persistent, you might start considering changing hard drive, otherwise one nice day it might break down

Comment: First order of business is to run fsck on the file system. Boot to the GRUB menu, choose Advanced Options, choose root access, type `fsck -f /dev/sdb1` and report back. Run fsck more than once if there are errors.

Comment: I booted in recovery mode and all seems to be well. If the problem persists I'll revert back to the file system check. Hopefully it won't fsck up any more. Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Looks like I forgot a step in my previous comment... select recovery mode. Go ahead and do the fsck anyway. It'll only take a minute or two, and it'll give you some peace of mind.